# Microbit v2 radio HiFive Inventor esp32

Tags: bbc-microbit

While there is also a microbit forum this is quite specific to having both a microbit and hifive inventor device. I was curious if anyone has done it.

Question is:
Of course I know the difference in the boards as I will state below. I just can't get radio to work between the two which should be possible as there are arduinos and such that can use radio with the microbit (I am doing this out of simplicity).

Microbit uses nordic semiconductor bluetooth chip and the Hifive uses esp32 for wifi and bluetooth.
Similarities are both are part of bbc collaborative boards and both come with relatively same libraries (radio) in micropython.

I use the same group setting radio.config(group = 1) <- for both boards. Neither are getting messages.

Code would look like in general but not exact (don't worry about python syntax issues here as far as indentation or if I missed a semicolon anywhere, I am just writing it out here).
Same exact code needed for both boards.

```
radio.config(group = 1) 

radio.on()
radio.send("hello") is for the send board only

while True:
  if radio.receive = "hello":
   print(radio.receive)
```

Comment: I thought `radio` was specific to the micro:bit, and not available on other MicroPython platforms? Anyway, if this is possible then the best place to ask will be on the [MicroPython forum](https://forum.micropython.org/)

Comment: That is a good idea. 

Ya, Hifive does have radio. Because it is a different architecture chipset wise, could run into an issue. 
I am pretty sure that Hifive to Hifive connectivity would work just like Microbit to Microbit. I am so curious if it would just out the box do that with a Microbit V2.

Radio isn't microbit specific I believe. People have gotten other project working. problem is firmware based of that particular development board and how much customization is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe unrelated, but I noticed that BOTH my boards (they are microbit V2) need to actually SEND a message for them to work. This is different from the older V1 where you could have one board ONLY for listening.

---

"radio.send("hello") is for the send board only"

---

I just send a dummy message at start and it works. Don't ask me why!